# overloading conditionally in php

Tags: php, preprocessor, overloading

Might be I am missing something obvious.
I have a native class with set and get method.

```
class DBStorage extends NativeClass{
  public function get($key);
  public function set($key,value);
}
```

I would like to use that most of the time, but, if I turn on the system DEBUG flag.
I would like the `set` and `get` methods to be overloaded with the following:

```
IF DEBUG IS ON{
    class DBStorage extends NativeClass{
      public function get($key){
         var_dump($key);
         parent::get($key);
      }
      public function set($key,$value){
         var_dump($key,$value);
         parent::set($key,$value);
      }
    }
}
```

NativeClass is written in C. It is an extension (phpredis, but it is not relevant).
How would I accomplish this?
I am on the 5.3 branch of PHP.

just to make sure...if debug is off, `DBStorage` will be:

```
 class DBStorage extends NativeClass{}
```

if debug is on, it will be:

```
class DBStorage extends NativeClass{
      public function get($key){
         var_dump($key);
         parent::get($key);
      }
      public function set($key,$value){
         var_dump($key,$value);
         parent::set($key,$value);
      }
    }
```

I do try to avoid the cluttring of IFs (there are dozens of functions in the real class)

```
public function get($key) {
       if (DEBUG) {
           var_dump($key);
       }
       return parent::get($key);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something just came to me

```
class nodebug extends NativeClass{
  static public function create(){
        if(DEBUG) return new DebugNativeClass;
        return new self;
  }
}

class DebugNativeClass extends nodebug{
    public function set($key,$value){
       var_dump($key,$value);
       parent::set($key,$value);
    }

    public function get($key){
       var_dump($key);
       return parent::set($key);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ya I wouldn't suggest this. For the record, classes containing factory methods should NOT be part of the object being instantiated. The idea of extending from a debug class is also not a great idea, as it limits the ability to extend from a better, more concrete class in the future.

Answer (score 4):

You can't conditionally overload, but you can conditionally do something in the overloaded method:

```
class DBStorage extends NativeClass{

    public function get($key) {
       if (DEBUG) {
           var_dump($key);
       }
       return parent::get($key);
    }

}
```

If debug is off, it passes the arguments right through to the parent method and returns the parent's return value, as if nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial code won't compile, because of the if around the class construct. Why not just make available a debug member variable, and if true, echo output, or push into a log file?

```
class NativeClass
{
    public $debug = false;
}

class DBStorage extends NativeClass
{
    public function get($key)
    {
        if (true === $this->debug) {
            error_log(sprintf('Key: %s', $key));
        }

        parent::get($key);
    }
}

// Calling code
$dbo = new DBStorage();

$dbo->debug = true;

$dbo->doStuff();
```

Comment: I know it won't comile, it is pseudo code to show what I try to achieve. As for your suggestion, while it will obviously work, is not what I try to do here (see last comment in my question)

Comment: So you want to conditionally check if in debug mode, without the conditions?

Comment: yep - see above what I came up with.

Comment: Ok, so you want to duplicate an entire class (or methods) for which you want debugging info, to avoid using multiple conditionals?

Comment: The original class is in C, My none debug class is only adding methods. I want to attach output to logs, only in the debug class, to each of the data manipulation methods, which exists only in the original class.

Comment: So you have two classes which will extend the class in C? 'none debug', and 'debug', and only the debug class will output debug info, but both child classes will have the same methods?

Comment: the debug class will inherit the none debug class. There is no need to overload the native class methods, except for adding debug output. So, right now, they way I see this is the way to write less code.  Was wondering though if PHP has a magic method that will even shorten this

Comment: Ya, then your solution would work. Although I wouldn't name it `create`, I'd name it `factory` as you expect an instaniated object to e returned, based on possible config options (i.e. debug flag).

Comment: I use the factory in my response, that instantiate for me the right class (debug class or nondebug class)